# How to align images under variable heights of text while maintaining Bootstrap Grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am faced with the challenge to vertical align images inside a Bootstrap grid under text with different height containers.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/abayob/L6d4b0os/3/)

**This is what it is now:**
[image: Current]

**This is what I want to achieve:**
[image: Target]

I would like to do this without the use of JavaScript, because that will only help the responsiveness.

I have tried:

1. Using `flexbox`, but I can't get the images to stick to the bottom
2. Give `figure` the property `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:bottom`, but the containers are not the same height without `flexbox`
3. Positioning the figure `absolute` and `bottom:0;`, but this (ofcourse) messes with the parent containers height.

The HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3"> 
    <p>
      Some text here
    </p>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dapibus suscipit nisl id sagittis. Suspendisse ex neque, tempus a bibendum eget, elementum eget lorem. Integer ultricies turpis eget nibh pulvinar, at facilisis diam dapibus. Quisque non turpis eget libero consequat fringilla vel et sem.
    </p>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p>
      Some text here
    </p>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can work.

The trick obviously is to give the columns equal height be setting the `.row` div to `display:flex`.

Then each columns *also* need `display:flex` but `flex-direction:column`.

Finally we set the `figure` to `margin-top:auto` to "push" it to the bottom in each case.

```css
.row.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.row.flex >div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row.flex > div figure {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row flex">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p>
      Some text here
    </p>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dapibus suscipit nisl id sagittis. Suspendisse ex neque, tempus a bibendum eget, elementum eget lorem. Integer ultricies turpis eget nibh pulvinar, at facilisis diam dapibus. Quisque non
      turpis eget libero consequat fringilla vel et sem.
    </p>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p>
      Some text here
    </p>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks great, I will try this solution!